# LWC - Red Error Bar Reads "Error in fetching record: invalid record id."

Tags: lightning-web-components, error-messages

**tl; dr** - How do I fix the error message shown in the screenshot below?

**Overview**

I am attempting to create a lightning web component that displays the field values of a record related to an Event record. Initial testing with a hard-coded record Id was successful, but attempts to dynamically acquire the record Id from a lookup field on the Event record have proven difficult.

With the assistance of user [Avi Rai](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/77637/avi-rai) I was able to use get the needed field values from an apex call, and the component is now showing the correct, record-specific field data. However, despite the record being correctly found, a large red error message appears at the top of the component reading "Error in fetching record: invalid record id."

**Question**

Why is his error message occurring (despite the fact that the record is being correctly found), and what can I do to remove this error message?

**Screenshot of error:**

[image]

html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Meeting Notes">
            <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
                <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={meetingNotesId} object-api-name="Meeting_Note__c">
                    <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
                    MeetingNoteId : --|{meetingNotesId}|--
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Running_Log_Coaching__c"></lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Running_Log_Financial_Services__c"></lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-button
                        class="slds-m-top_small"
                        variant="brand"
                        type="submit"
                        name="update"
                        label="Update">
                    </lightning-button>
                </lightning-record-edit-form>
            </p>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

js

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getSObjectValue } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getMeetingNote from '@salesforce/apex/TaskEventUtility.getMeetingNote';

import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Meeting_Note__c.Id';

export default class DisplayMeetingNotes extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    @wire(getMeetingNote, { eventId: '$recordId'})
    meeting;

    get meetingNotesId(){
        return this.meeting.data ? getSObjectValue(this.meeting.data, ID_FIELD) : 'Bob';
    }

}
```

apex

```
 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
 public static Meeting_Note__c getMeetingNote(Id eventId){
     Id meetingNoteId = [SELECT Id, Meeting_Notes__c FROM Event WHERE Id = :eventId LIMIT 1].Meeting_Notes__c;
     return [SELECT Id, Running_Log_Coaching__c, Running_Log_Financial_Services__c,
                FROM Meeting_Note__c WHERE Id = :meetingNoteId];
 }
```

Comment: Don't return 'Bob' if there is no data in meeting.data... return null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the error is there because in the time between retrieving the Meeting_Note__c record, the RecordEditForm is being supplied with an Id of 'Bob'.

'Bob' is an invalid id - while I know eventually you provide a valid id, you should change this to null (or perhaps ""). This will mean the form won't complain and you won't get that nasty red error message.